# C# Date/Time format for database storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

Can anyone advise on the best way to format the following date string format...

**Sat, Sep 22**

to something that I can store in SQL Server as a date/time...

using format such as **YYYY/MM/DD**

I could do this in code, but I am reading hundreds of xml extracts not sure how best to approach this.

Comment: How do you know what year it is with `Sat, Sep 22`? Is the assumption that the year is the current (2012) year?

Comment: Yes, see my comment to the answer from  @davehale23.  If the DOW does not match the current year you will receive an error.

Comment: SQL Server supports a `DateTime` structure I would use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DateTime.Parse()`  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) for info.   Although, you'll have to have a year in there somewhere.

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse("Sat, Sep 22 2012");
```

EDIT:

Since we're not sure if you know what year you are dealing with, I suggest that you might use something like this:

```
Int32 thisYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
string aDate = "Sat, Sep 22";
DateTime outDate;
while (!DateTime.TryParse(aDate + " " + thisYear.ToString(), out outDate))        
    thisYear--;
```

This will get the DateTime for the most recent year that fits the description.  If you try to use an `aDate` of "Fri, Sep 22", then your result will be "9/22/2006".

Or, if you just want to use 'this year' you could just use this:

```
String[] myDate = ("Fri, Sep 22").Split(',');
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(myDate[1].ToString());
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse() does not require a date.  It will take the input as provided by the poster and assume the current year.

Comment: I was hoping it would be "smart" enough to determine the year based upon the day of week, but trying "Sat, Sep 24" (which would be 2011) just gave the error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.

Comment: @McArthey,  I just tried that in my IDE.  YOU ARE SO RIGHT!  I learn something new every day.  I didn't know that it would assume current year.

Comment: Yeah, the "smart" thing would be difficult to predict.  At that point it wouldn't know which "Sat, Sep 24" you wanted.

Comment: But. . . I can't go home yet, I haven't finished my bacon!

Comment: As @McArthey pointed out, you will get an exception if "Sep 22" fell on a Tuesday this year.   Check out my edits for some options.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParse("Sat, Sep 22", out result);
Response.Write(result.ToString("yyyy/M/dd"));
```

This will parse without the year.  In this case the output is "2012/9/22".

Comment: Tried this but gives a value such as '0001/1/01'

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.90).aspx.  When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or DateTime.MinValue if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null, is an empty string (""), or does not contain a valid string representation of a date and time.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports some specific date formats. You may use `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Please check the following code:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You should not worry about how the date is stored. You can display the date in any format you want and it can be done in SQL Server as well as .Net.

[see reference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/316312-How-add-date-time-sql-databae-using-c.aspx)